# On the divergence of Ricci Tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to prove in an index-free notation the following result:
\begin{equation}
div(ric)= \frac{1}{2} ds
\end{equation}
whrere I have used the following notations
\begin{equation}
\text{ric}(X,Y) = g(R_{e_j X} Y, e_j) \
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{div}(\text{ric}) = (\nabla_{e_i} \text{ric})(e_i, X)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
s = \text{ric}(e_j, e_j)
\end{equation}

with Einstein summation convention.
I've tried to use the property of $\nabla$ with contraction but I didn't manage to find the result.

Comment: You seem to be using indices in your equations. It might be possible to write a proof without using any indices at all, but it doesn't seem worth the trouble.

Comment: Can you please proofread all your equations? This doesn't make sense to me, anyhow.

Comment: I'm working in an orthonormal frame $(e_1,  ..., e_n)$ and those are the definitions found in my teacher's notes on differential geometry. What I mean by "index-free notation" is working without using the index notation for tensors.

Comment: $R_{e_jX}Y$? $(\nabla_{e_i}\text{ric})(e_i,X)$?